# Open android native google maps app obtaining directions starting from current position

Tags: android, google-maps, url-parameters

I'm trying to open google maps from my application, setting a route from the phone current position to a fixed position. I'm using this code:

```
String uri = "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=&daddr=example";        
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(i);
```

The problem is that I don't know what to put in saddr= to reference my current position. I've found many other questions like this but no answer worked (such as leaving saddr= empty or saddr=Current, they don't work).

I don't want to use native android locator, I just want to know if there's a way to ask google maps "start from my current position".

Comment: If you click on marker of map, it should go to google navigation? or you want to draw routes from current location?

Comment: I want my application to setup directly using intent call the map to display the route from current location to the fixed location, so that the user doesn't need to setup navigation by himself

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can explicitly to it to open in direction mode with an `f=d` parameter. With that set and no start address, it should use the device's current location. So more like this:

`"https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr=berlin"`

**Note:** This doesn't work in a browser; it opens the directions page with a blank field for start. Used in an intent sent to the native maps application, it works correctly(at least on my 4.2.2 gNex).

Comment: This is very useful. If you want to use a start address other than your own location, modify the url as `"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=hamburg&daddr=berlin"`. Also works in browser(at least in Chrome).

Answer (score 4):

in above post

https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr=berlin

It will ask you for source address it will not automatically pass your source address you need to select it on  map by taping,

You can use GPS for that purpose... after getting the LatLng coordinates  you can pass them to url...but it should be in f=a not f=d..

https://maps.google.com/maps?f=a@saddr=LatLng&daddr=badlapur

Comment: It still taking Your Location as Source Address. Any idea how to make it work or specific step?

Answer (score 2):

I just used this and it opened straight to google maps in navigation mode from my current location to the address specified in the text variable. text should be in the same format as you would type it in the search bar your self

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+text));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

please make url like this

https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr=newdelhi

but make one more thing clear

in  manifiest file: use a INTERNET PERMISSION

otherwise it will crash

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"https://www.google.com/maps/dir//41.3951982,-72.855568/41.279386,-72.825098"
```

You can have multiple locations, but starting location will be current location.